# How do I convert Binary string to scala string in spark scala

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading an avro file which contains a field as binary string, I need to convert it into a java.lang.string to pass it to another library(spark-xml-util), how do I convert it into java.lang.string efficiently. This is the code I have got so far : -

```
    val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("filePath/fileName.avro")
    df.select("myField").collect().mkString
```

The last line gives me the following exception: -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getString(Row.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getString(rows.scala:165)
```

df schema is: -

```
root
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- myField: binary (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

---

Considering the state of the API right now (2.2.0), your best call is to create a UDF to do just that and replace the column :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val toString = udf((payload: Array[Byte]) => new String(payload))
df.withColumn("myField", toString(df("myField")))
```

or if as you seem to imply the data is compressed using GZIP you can :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val toString = udf((payload: Array[Byte]) => {
  val inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(payload))
  scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).mkString
})
df.withColumn("myField", toString(df("myField")))
```

Comment: I tried this, but all it gives me is junk values. This however works fine 
`val inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(binPayldRec.getAs[Array[Byte]]("myfield")))
   val xmlString = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).mkString`

I don't understand why one works and the other doesn't

Comment: well as you wrote because it seems the array[byte] is not a pure string it's a GZIP compressed string just use the same code as a UDF and it should work.

Comment: Fully qualified classes, 

`val gzipBinaryToString = udf((payload: Array[Byte]) => {
  val inputStream = new java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(payload))
  scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).mkString
})`

Answer (score 6):

In Spark 3.0 you can cast between BINARY and STRING data.

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(Seq("ABC", "BCD", "CDE", "DEF")).toDF("value")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> df.select($"value", $"value".cast("BINARY"), 
$"value".cast("BINARY").cast("STRING")).show()
+-----+----------+-----+
|value|     value|value|
+-----+----------+-----+
|  ABC|[41 42 43]|  ABC|
|  BCD|[42 43 44]|  BCD|
|  CDE|[43 44 45]|  CDE|
|  DEF|[44 45 46]|  DEF|
+-----+----------+-----+
```

I don't have your data to test with, but you should be able to do:

```
df.select($"myField".cast("STRING"))
```

This obviously depends on the actual data (i.e. don't cast a JPEG to STRING) but assuming it's UTF-8 encoded this should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the previous solution, the code `new String(payload)` did not work for me on true binary data.

Ultimately the solution was a little more involved, with the length of the binary data required as a 2nd parameter.

```
def binToString(payload: Array[Byte], payload_length: Int): String = {
  val ac: Array[Char] = Range(0,payload_length).map(i => payload(i).toChar).toArray
  return ac.mkString 
}

val binToStringUDF = udf( binToString(_: Array[Byte], _: Int): String )
```